# Creating an algorithm for selecting multiple lottery numbers (mathematics and statistics)

Tags: java, algorithm, math, statistics

In the Spanish bet system there is a concept called `multiple` which means that if the game you want to play has bets of 6 numbers, you can create a special bet of 7 or 8 numbers, or even 9, 10 or 11 numbers. That special bet will traduce in X normal bets of 6 numbers which will combine the given numbers.

```
The multiple bet of 7 numbers will traduce in 7 bets of 6 numbers. 
The multiple bet of 8 numbers will traduce in 28 bets of 6 numbers.
The multiple bet of 9 numbers will traduce in 84 bets of 6 numbers.
The multiple bet of 10 numbers will traduce in 210 bets of 6 numbers.
The multiple bet of 11 numbers will traduce in 462 bets of 6 numbers.
```

Sample of multiple of 7 with the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7:

> 234567 134567 124567 123567 123467 123457 123456

Sample of multiple of 8 with the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8:

> 123456 123457 123458 123467 123468 123478 123567 123568 123578 123678
>   124567 124568 124578 124678 125678 134567 134568 134578 134678 135678
>   145678 234567 234568 234578 234678 235678 245678 345678

My first goal is to achieve an algorithm in Java for generate `multiples`. I mean, each bet has a cost of 1 coin, so, given for example 30 numbers and 800 coins, waste the 800 coins in X multiple bets of X numbers. The multiple bets must combine the 30 numbers in more or less equal quantity of appearances.

The total cost of the multiples must be near of 800 euros, can be a little less but never be more than 800 euros. **The algorithm will offer different proposals, for example, can offer a result near of 800 euros with multiples of 7, a result near of 800 with multiples of 8, etc... and the user will select which one prefers.** I have no idea of how to achieve this.

In this website there is a web multiple generator which can generate multiples of 7 and of 8, but it's code is not public: http://www.miramiprimi.miraestudio.es/MetodoMultiplePrimitiva.php

Comment: The algorithm used on the given resource is super simple. Are you sure you would like to use it as well or you are more interested in more randomization added to the permutations generated?

Comment: @dbl yes I'm absolutely sure that i need that algorithm. Someone has voted this for close, I don't understand why. Please, can you make an answer with your algorithm to show people that this is a good question with answers? thank you soo much

Comment: You are trying to reinvent this wheel (haha): [Lottery Wheeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lottery_wheeling). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

@NullPointerException what I meant earlier today is that the algorithm applied on the given URL is pretty much a brute force algo for generating all the combinations of length 6 out of N symbols set. Code for it is pretty straight forward:

```
private static List<List<Integer>> bruteForce(List<Integer> numbers) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> current;
    for (int position1 = 0; position1 < numbers.size(); position1++) {
        for (int position2 = position1 + 1; position2 < numbers.size(); position2++) {
            for (int position3 = position2 + 1; position3 < numbers.size(); position3++) {
                for (int position4 = position3 + 1; position4 < numbers.size(); position4++) {
                    for (int position5 = position4 + 1; position5 < numbers.size(); position5++) {
                        for (int position6 = position5 + 1; position6 < numbers.size(); position6++) {
                            current = new ArrayList<>();

                            current.add(numbers.get(position1));
                            current.add(numbers.get(position2));
                            current.add(numbers.get(position3));
                            current.add(numbers.get(position4));
                            current.add(numbers.get(position5));
                            current.add(numbers.get(position6));

                            result.add(current);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and then some use cases: // just have in mind it works for array_length >= 6!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers;

    System.out.println("N = 6, resulting in 1 element in the list.");
    numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ add(1); add(2); add(3); add(4); add(5); add(6);}};
    bruteForce(numbers).forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("N = 7, resulting in 7 element in the list.");
    numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ add(1); add(2); add(3); add(4); add(5); add(6); add(7);}};
    bruteForce(numbers).forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("N = 8, resulting in 28 element in the list.");
    numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ add(1); add(2); add(3); add(4); add(5); add(6); add(7); add(8);}};
    bruteForce(numbers).forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("N = 9, resulting in 84 element in the list.");
    numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ add(1); add(2); add(3); add(4); add(5); add(6); add(7); add(8); add(9);}};
    bruteForce(numbers).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

and the output will be:

```
N = 6, resulting in 1 element in the list.
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
N = 7, resulting in 7 element in the list.
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
N = 8, resulting in 28 element in the list.
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
[1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
N = 9, resulting in 84 element in the list.
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
[1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Just have in mind that the numbers used in the output comes from the definition of `List<Integer> numbers = ...` so you can play around and test it further. Also I would suggest using an ordered set instead of list in the case.

Like:

```
numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ add(11); add(22); add(33); add(44); add(45); add(46); add(47);}};
bruteForce(numbers).forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints:

```
[11, 22, 33, 44, 45, 46]
[11, 22, 33, 44, 45, 47]
[11, 22, 33, 44, 46, 47]
[11, 22, 33, 45, 46, 47]
[11, 22, 44, 45, 46, 47]
[11, 33, 44, 45, 46, 47]
[22, 33, 44, 45, 46, 47]
```

Screen shot from the URL quoted:

[image]

I will add you the recursive implementation of very same method that will take as input parameter the base (subset length) as well.

```
private static List<List<Integer>> bruteForceRecursive(List<Integer> numbers, List<Integer> indexes, int base) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    if (indexes.size() == base) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        indexes.forEach(x -> list.add(numbers.get(x)));
        result.add(list);

        return result;
    }

    for (int i = indexes.isEmpty() ? 0 : indexes.get(indexes.size() - 1) + 1; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        indexes.add(i);
        result.addAll(bruteForceRecursive(numbers, indexes, base));
        indexes.remove(indexes.size() - 1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

and then the example of usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers;

    numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ add(11); add(22); add(33); add(44); add(45); add(46); add(47);}};

    bruteForceRecursive(numbers, new ArrayList<>(), 2).forEach(System.out::println);
    bruteForceRecursive(numbers, new ArrayList<>(), 4).forEach(System.out::println);
    bruteForceRecursive(numbers, new ArrayList<>(), 6).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

that prints:

```
[11, 22]
[11, 33]
[11, 44]
[11, 45]
[11, 46]
[11, 47]
[22, 33]
[22, 44]
[22, 45]
[22, 46]
[22, 47]
[33, 44]
[33, 45]
[33, 46]
[33, 47]
[44, 45]
[44, 46]
[44, 47]
[45, 46]
[45, 47]
[46, 47]
[11, 22, 33, 44]
[11, 22, 33, 45]
[11, 22, 33, 46]
[11, 22, 33, 47]
[11, 22, 44, 45]
[11, 22, 44, 46]
[11, 22, 44, 47]
[11, 22, 45, 46]
[11, 22, 45, 47]
[11, 22, 46, 47]
[11, 33, 44, 45]
[11, 33, 44, 46]
[11, 33, 44, 47]
[11, 33, 45, 46]
[11, 33, 45, 47]
[11, 33, 46, 47]
[11, 44, 45, 46]
[11, 44, 45, 47]
[11, 44, 46, 47]
[11, 45, 46, 47]
[22, 33, 44, 45]
[22, 33, 44, 46]
[22, 33, 44, 47]
[22, 33, 45, 46]
[22, 33, 45, 47]
[22, 33, 46, 47]
[22, 44, 45, 46]
[22, 44, 45, 47]
[22, 44, 46, 47]
[22, 45, 46, 47]
[33, 44, 45, 46]
[33, 44, 45, 47]
[33, 44, 46, 47]
[33, 45, 46, 47]
[44, 45, 46, 47]
[11, 22, 33, 44, 45, 46]
[11, 22, 33, 44, 45, 47]
[11, 22, 33, 44, 46, 47]
[11, 22, 33, 45, 46, 47]
[11, 22, 44, 45, 46, 47]
[11, 33, 44, 45, 46, 47]
[22, 33, 44, 45, 46, 47]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your approach, it's useful but maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. OK I apreciate a lot your sample of code, but the algorithm I'm searching for will generate the "multiples" of 7, 8, 9 10 or 11 numbers. Yes, that multiples are equivalent to 7, 28, 84, etc bets of 6 numbers, but I'm not searching for the bets of 6 numbers, I'm searching for the "multiples" bets of 7,8,9,10 or 11 numbers which are equivalent to the bets returned by your function.

Comment: For example, if the user want's to expend 500 euros with 20 numbers, the program will show as a result the options in "multiples" that will use these 20 numbers equally, or more or less equally and that are equivalent to 500 euros (or a little less). For example, the result could be something similar to: if you want multiples of 7, 500/7 = 71, so the program will return you 71 multiples of 7 which will combine the 20 numbers equally in bets of 7 numbers. Internally these 71 multiples of 7 numbers will be equivalent to 71x7 = 497 bets. Do you understand me now?

Comment: I think that you are not understanding the requirement. For 20 symbols set there are 38760 different combinations that are unique and all of them are produced by the code provided. This is also how the *not open source algorithm* is working as well.

Comment: In the case where you will have as input N (multiples base) and then M symbols(N < M), and then Q(the amount to spend) then there are different stategies for that. First clarify the question in a such manner though. A possible approach could be: *create subsets of length N out of the set containing M Symbols, while the generated results are less than Q*.

Comment: The brute force algo I've posted could be easily reworked as a recursive function to accomulate sublists of arbitrary length -> not as it is like 6 for now. Then use this algo to generate `subsets of length 7` out of the 20 one, then iterate trough them to generate `subsets of length 6`, while their count is less than 500 or `subsets of length 7` has more elements. If the `subsets of length 7`  are all used and you still has some money to spend then there are different strategies as well...

Comment: thanks, sorry for my bad way for express the question. I dont have good english, I think I'm having dificulties to explain the concept of "multiple". If the user want to expend 500 coins with 20 numbers in Multiples of 7 numbers for this lottery which only accept bets of 6 numbers, then, as 500/7 = 71, the system will calculate 71 multiples of 7 numbers. Each multiple of 7 numbers is equivalent to 7 normal bets of 6 numbers as I explained with examples on the question text. Also the main rule is that the 20 numbers of the user will be equally (as possible) used in those 71 combinations

Comment: So I'm not sure how to change that algorithm to fit that requirement, also, the user will be able to select multiples of 7,8,9,10 or 11, not only 7, but I think that will be the same with minor changes in the algorithm.

Comment: in your algorithm I can see the resultant X 6 number bets when you pass a multiple of Y, but that is not what I am searching for, In the case of multiples of 7, I need to calculate the 71 multiples for that 500 euros of the example of my comment. That 71 multiples of 7 will use equally the 20 numbers. So probably that whould be one of the main problems, that the 20 numbers must be used equally in that multiples. Did I explain myself beter now? thank you

Comment: I do understand what are your requirement now but I'm not in the position to spend that much time making a research for it. I can not help any more than already did. I've added the recursion method in my answer. This answer isn't aiming to fulfill your requirements, just to give you enough details on where to begin. Please consider @AakashM comment as it holds the key to the math you are looking for. Good luck.

Comment: thank you so much @dbl tomorrow I will investigate your new sample and that comment